# C++ can't search other even order names

Tags: c++

Good Day to All, I'm asking for a help on how to fix my code about searching a file in c++,

sample text(test.txt):

```
name: jason statham
age: 19

name: jeremy renner
age: 17

name: kim tak gu
age: 18

name: donnie yen
age: 20
```

this is my code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<istream>
#include<windows.h>

void search() //function only of my main program
{
string name="", searchname;
string age="";

ifstream search_sample("test.txt");

cout<<"Enter name to be search: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, searchname);

size_t pos;
while(search_sample.good())
{
    getline(search_sample, name);
    getline(search_sample, age);
    pos=name.find(searchname);

        if(pos!=string::npos)
            {
                cout<<"\nRecord Found\n\n";
                cout<<name<<"\n";
                cout<<age<<"\n";
                break;
            }
}   
getch();
main();
}
```

when searching jason statham and kim tak gu(those who are in odd positions) they were found and display in command prompt, then when i start searching those who are in even positions they not found and not display in command prompt, can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Jason Statham is way older than nineteen.

Comment: @us2012 yes thats the actual format of my text file, sorry im new here. so how can i fix it? if i remove the       `getline(search_sample, age)` the age will not display in command prompt.

Comment: @BrianCain hahaha! :D its just an example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that empty lines are lines as well. For the first person `name` and `age` are read correctly, but in the next iteration of the loop, `name` will be empty because `getline(search_sample, name)` reads the empty line.

Comment: Read the blank line. You're reading the other lines, what's so hard about reading a blank line?

Comment: Find a way to ignore empty lines, or read john's answer if you don't feel like thinking about it :P .

Comment: i get it, sorry, i fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @us2012 one last thing i wanna ask, how can i make my search case insensitive? when i search it is always case sensitive. ex: **Donnie Yen** when i search **donnie** it didnt display the searched name.

Comment: @user2803376 Look at `std::tolower`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower

Answer (score 1):

```
getline(search_sample, name);
getline(search_sample, age);
getline(search_sample, blank_line);
```

seems like an improvement.

Comment: Thanks! one last thing i wanna ask, how can i make my search case insensitive? when i search it is always case sensitive. ex: **Donnie Yen** when i search _donnie_ it didnt display the searched name.

Comment: Easiest way to do that is to convert both strings to upper case before you search. And the easiest way to convert strings to upper case is ... I'll leave you to research that.